# How can I get fuse mount options?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fuse

I am using a small fuse filesystem which bootstraps as usual by calling

```
fuse_main(argc, argv, &fsoperations, NULL)
```

in the `main(int argc, char *argv[])` function. `fuse_main` will then parse options etc. At some point in the filesystem, I need to obtain some mount options as set by passing `-o` to the process. The only way I figured out so far is to parse `/proc/mounts` (or `/etc/mtab`) or manually parsing the command line, both options are far from optimal. Is there a fuse API or anything else I can use to obtain the mount options?